# PHP SDK Facebook graph API send App-to-User Notifications using CRON job

Tags: facebook-graph-api, notifications, cron, facebook-php-sdk

### Trying to send a scheduled notification to an app user.

The user specify a reminder time that is stored in a MySQL database and using a cron job.
I want to send notification 3 times a day; upon user prefered time (using local time).

I setup the cron to run once every 30 min.

```
<?php
function runCurl($path)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $path);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    return $output;
    curl_close($ch);
}
function getAppUsers()
{
}
function build_batch_request()
{
}
$graph_url    = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=xxx&client_secret=xxx&grant_type=client_credentials&redirect_uri=https://www.example.com/app/";
$result       = runCurl($graph_url);
$access_token = json_decode($result)->access_token;
$graph_url    = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/notifications?access_token=$access_token&template=Test Message";
$result       = runCurl($graph_url);
print_r($result); // for debug only
?>
```

I am getting error that says that ***something went wrong*** from Facebook graph API.

**Update:** question clarified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my code mistakes:

- message template needs to be URL Encoded:
- Also I needed to make sure I am getting the app access token.
- I needed to debug and find out if database is returning values

Here is a tested and working code:
I am include the whole cron code; please feel free to edit for optimization and add your input.

```
<?php



 if(isset($_GET["key"]) || !empty($_GET["key"]) )
            {

    //  will be used later when creating a cron job; to prevent direct access to file
    if($_GET["key"]=='YOUR_KEY_HERE')
        {
                            require_once 'Facebook/autoload.php';


                            define('APPID', 'YOUR_APP_ID_HERE');
                            define('APPSECRET', 'YOUR_APP_SECRET_HERE');
                            define('CANVASURL', 'YOUR_CANVAS_URL_HERE');


                            // function to run CURL
                            function runCurl($path)
                            {
                                    $ch = curl_init();
                                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $path);
                                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
                                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
                                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
                                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
                                    $output = curl_exec($ch);
                                    return $output;
                                    curl_close($ch);
                            }

                            // function to send batch notification to app user
                            function notify()
                            {
                                    $fb = new Facebook\Facebook(
                                    ['app_id' => 'APPID',
                                    'app_secret' => 'APPSECRET',
                                    'default_graph_version' => 'v2.10']);





                                    $gmt_time = gmdate("H:i:s", time());


                                    include_once 'db.php';
                                    // include your database configuration
                                    // recommending using PDO
                                    $db=connect();

                                    $get_users_list="select fb_userid, morning, afternoon, night ,utc_time from alarm where time_format(morning, '%H:%i') = time_format(UTC_TIME, '%H:%i') OR time_format(afternoon, '%H:%i') = time_format(UTC_TIME, '%H:%i') OR time_format(night, '%H:%i') = time_format(UTC_TIME, '%H:%i')";
                                    // getting a list of users that expecting a reminder notification;
                                    // as the server's is using UTC, we convert saved local time into UTC time
                                    // I can directly save in UTC when user input reminder time; but this is intended
                                    // echo $get_users_list; //DEBUG


                                    $result= $db->getDataListFromQuery($get_users_list);
                                    //var_dump('Query Result= '. $result[0]); // DEBUG
                                    if($result[0]>0)
                                    {
                                    // check if $result return data and not empty
                                            $graph_url= "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=". APPID . "&client_secret=" . APPSECRET . "&grant_type=client_credentials&redirect_uri=" . CANVASURL;

                                            echo $graph_url;


                                            $curlResult = runCurl($graph_url);
                                            $access_token = json_decode($curlResult)->access_token;
                                            var_dump($access_token); //DEBUG


                                    $fb->setDefaultAccessToken($access_token);
                                    $fb_usersList= []; // an arry to hold the users' IDs to wich notification will go.
                                    $tmpbatch = []; // an array to hold all requests in batch


                            foreach ($result as $row) {
                                         $fbUserID = $row['fb_userid'];
                                         $morning_alarm = $row['morning'];
                                         $afternoon_alarm = $row['afternoon'];
                                         $night_alarm = $row['night'];


                                         $morning_med = $row['morningmed'];
                                         $afternoon_med = $row['afternoonmed'];
                                         $night_med= $row['nightmed'];

                                         $now_utc= $row['utc_time'];


$now_utc = date('H:i', strtotime($now_utc));     // remove seconds from UTC TIME
$morning_alarm = date('H:i', strtotime($morning_alarm ));
$afternoon_alarm = date('H:i', strtotime($afternoon_alarm ));
$night_alarm=  date('H:i', strtotime($night_alarm));

if($morning_alarm ==$now_utc)
{
$template="Good Morning! Please remember to take your medicine: ($morning_med)";
}

if($afternoon_alarm==$now_utc)
{
$template="Good Afternoon! Please remember to take your medicine: ($afternoon_med)";
}

if($night_alarm==$now_utc)
{
$template="Good Evening! Please remember to take your medicine: ($night_med)";
}


$template=urlencode($template) . "&href=page.php";  // this will redirect users to page.php once they click on noticiation
//echo $template; //DEBUG






                                        $batch[]=$fb->request('POST', "/".$fbUserID."/notifications?template=$template");

                            }


                            try {
                              $responses = $fb->sendBatchRequest($batch);
                            } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
                              // When Graph returns an error
                              echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
                              exit;
                            } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
                              // When validation fails or other local issues
                              echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
                              exit;
                            }

                            foreach ($responses as $key => $response) {
                              if ($response->isError()) {
                                $e = $response->getThrownException();
                                echo '<p>Error! Facebook SDK Said: ' . $e->getMessage() . "\n\n";
                                echo '<p>Graph Said: ' . "\n\n";
                                var_dump($e->getResponse());
                              } else {
                                echo "<p> HTTP status code: " . $response->getHttpStatusCode() . "<br />\n";
                                echo "Response: " . $response->getBody() . "</p>\n\n";
                                echo "<hr />\n\n";
                              }
                            }
                            }

                            }

                             notify();
                             exit;
    }
}
exit;
?>
```

Please refer to this answer to learn [how to setup a cron task in linux server](https://serverfault.com/q/299287/406943).

I used this one :

```
curl --silent https://www.example.com/cron.php?key=somekey
```

Thanks for all hints; appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

From the link in your question:

> Apps can generate notifications by issuing a HTTP POST request to the
>   /user_id/notifications Graph API, with an **app access_token**.

You just need an App Access Token:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

Comment: is there please any code hint to working solution. most codes are outdated

Comment: i am not sure what code you need, just use php curl and make the post request. no need to use the php sdk.

Comment: what is the exact error message? please be more specific. and did you REALLY use an APP access token? it´s really simple to create one, just check out the links in my answer.

Comment: Yes I did use app access_token and verify it using fb access token debugger. all seem ok in curl which suppose to send notification from my server to app users, can't copy the error message as now I am getting (Sorry, something went wrong) message without changing the code.

Comment: make sure you activate the errors with curl, there are some settings for that. if it does not work, you should always get a reliable error message from the graph api.